# Drupal 7 custom template file for certain content type

Tags: php, templates, drupal, drupal-7

i am currently working on a drupal 7 project. I wrote a custom template for a certain content type. The file is named correctly `node--type.tpl.php` and it's displayed correctly too. but the other regions and blocks are not visible. other custom templates show all regions and blocks. I'd like to mention two things,

1. i'm not a drupal lover/hero
2. i'm expanding an existing project.

Comment: are you sure that you render correctly the regions in the template?

Comment: and may be you have open DIV tags ?

Comment: the template is being rendered correctly. i acctually made the content type, entered some content, made a tpl file with the correct name pattern node--type and put it in the templates folder. so i didn't change anything in the other template files. i've also tried with an empty file, so it cannot be an open html tag or php error.

Comment: @eyurdakul are there any restrictions on where to render a block? like show only on `<front>` or don't show one `node/*` etc..

Comment: i don't know, the other regions are visible on every page except my new template file. should i register it somewhere?

Comment: no it doesn't need to be registered somewhere, drupal automatically searches the templates folder of your theme..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things to check:

- Make sure you've also copied across the core node.tpl.php file to your theme folder; the template overrides for nodes won't work without it.
- Make sure your file is properly named, e.g. for a content type with the name of `home_page` the template file will be called `node--home_page.tpl.php`.
- Make sure you've cleared Drupal's caches since adding the new template files; the theme registry is cached so a clear is necessary to pick up changes.

See [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) for more information on the general subject.

As an aside, the node template file doesn't have any blocks/regions in it, they will always be contained in `page.tpl.php`, or some derivative.